# how to end a session in php with logging out

Tags: php, session

I started a session `$_SESSION['ProdID'] = $ProdID;` earlier in my code and I started another ProdID session in another page of my script.

I want to end the first one while this new one will be active without logging out.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: What do you mean with 'without logging out'? I assume there's another session variable that keeps track of the logged-in user. What do you mean with 'start another ProdID session'? Simply setting the variable value overwrites the old ID with a new ProdID.

Comment: Question title says `with logging out` and your questions says `without logging out`.  What is you really want?

Comment: I think @Tolu just wants to change the value of session variable $_SESSION['ProdID']. If it is so, he just needs to simply assign new value to $_SESSION['ProdID']

Comment: @Dhairya I want to end the session

Comment: @Muthu; am sorry, it was a typographical error. "without logging out"

Comment: you can have single session variable with name $_SESSION['ProdID'] through out your session. You said you have "started another ProdID session in another page" which means value of $_SESSION['ProdID'] is changed. so what is the problem?

Comment: I have many session variable but it's that I have to end $_SESSION['ProdID'] without logging out.

Answer (score 2):

Create a page with any name you want.
For example you create a page named as logout.php and paste this code in it.

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    session_destroy();
    header('location:login_page.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to destroy all sessions , it's better to use session_destroy()

if you want to destroy specific session , you can use unset($_SESSION['']);

Answer (score 1):

First destroy the current session by [regenerating a new session ID](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) to create new cookies. You can then set your values in the *new* session, the old session is destroyed. Optionally delete all old session variables if you don't need them any longer:

```
/* generate new session id and delete old session in store */
session_regenerate_id(true);

/* optional: unset old session variables */
$_SESSION = array();

/* set new value(s) */
$_SESSION['name'] = 'value';
```

If you still want to keep the old session (*"without logging out"*) you can remove the `true` parameter so the old session is kept in store:

```
/* generate new session id and keep old session in store */
session_regenerate_id();
```

The rest would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try using session_destroy(); to end your current session.

Answer (score 0):

Only type unset session end of code, 
Like this

```
unset($_SESSION['ProdID']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
unset($_SESSION["ProdID"]);
```